# CloudFormation error output

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, aws-cloudformation

I have this function in my template in CloudFormation:

```
"function error_exit\n",
"{\n",
"  cfn-signal -e 1 -r \"$1\" '", { "Ref" : "WebServerWaitHandle" }, "'\n",
"  exit 1\n",
"}\n",
```

It prints out in the resources when an error occurs, because this line:

```
sudo puppet apply --verbose --debug --environment=qa /puppet.pp > /tmp/puppet.log 2>&1 || error_exit 'failed to apply puppet manifests'\n",
```

But i want to show what error is in the `/tmp/puppet.log`, something like `grep Error /tmp/puppet.log`

Comment: This is not whole `user data`, the two parts have no relationship. Please paste the whole (or most parts), especially related with `puppet apply`